# How to find specific character in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, contains

I have a string like `a>5 and b<6 or c>=7` in java

When I check whether string contains `>` then output is true for both `>` and `>=`

How can I restrict my check only to specific character?

How can I use `matches` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just threw this together based on the updated specifications. Basically a real simple parser rather mechanically created: (And I'm not good with naming at 7 in the morning oh well)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "a > b >= c > x";
        Main m = new Main(test);
        System.out.println(m.getTokenNumber());

        test = "aasdfasdf asdfdasf";
        m = new Main(test);
        System.out.println(m.getTokenNumber());
    }

    private String input;
    private int pos;

    public Main(String input) {
        this.input = input;
        pos = 0;
    }

    public TokenNumber getTokenNumber() {
        TokenNumber tokenNumber = new TokenNumber();
        Token t = nextToken();
        while (t != Token.NONE) {
            tokenNumber.addToken(t);
            t = nextToken();
        }
        return tokenNumber;
    }

    private Token nextToken() {
        while (pos < input.length() && input.charAt(pos) != '>') pos++;
        if (pos == input.length()) return Token.NONE;
        pos++;
        if (pos == input.length() || input.charAt(pos) != '=') return Token.GREATER;
        return Token.GREATER_EQUAL;
    }

    enum Token {
        GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL, NONE;
    }

    static class TokenNumber {
        public int greater;
        public int greater_than;

        public void addToken(Token t) {
            if (t == Token.GREATER) greater++;
            else greater_than++;
            assert t != Token.NONE;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Greater: %d%nGreater Than: %d", greater, greater_than);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this is really superb code but suppose I have string as suggested by @alf a > 5 and s == "<br/>" then your code is counting > of br also. But I need to count only > of a > 5 i.e. only > symbol which really indicates > in condition and not > symbol used to close the tag..

Comment: @SRK the solution will stay almost the same, you only add support for additional tokens. Basically, you need to create a lexer for your code, and once you've got the stream of tokens, you can check whether there was a token `>`. Strings are catered for by a grammar rule allowing a *string-literal* token. Unfortunately, it's going to be a good article explaining the topic—or a book, so try starting with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278480/antlr-tutorials — there are nice tutorials there.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is, you think of a lexical entity, `>=`, as of a "character." That will bite you more than once, as there actually are two characters, `>` and `=`, and `>` is indeed here. So depending on what you need, the answer may be different.

Why don't you want to see `>=` found?

What usage of `>` is of interest for you? Will e.g. `<tag>some text</tag>` be a proper string which you'd prefer to allow?

Comment: @alf my interest is that my input string will be query and I want to distinguish between condition containing > and >=..

I know that >= contains > and thats why CONTAINS function gives true..

So that is what I am asking how to solve it...?

Comment: @SRK what does "query" mean? if a query happen to have `a < 5 and s == "<br/>"`, will that `>` count as the one you need or not? In order to _solve_ a problem, you need to _define_ a problem. So far, it's not defined at all.

Comment: @alf yes you are right... <br/> should not be counted as a greater than. I tried CONTAINS and REPLACE both but still cant find the solution.

Comment: @SRK see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278480/antlr-tutorials for further help :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to discriminate between *greater than* and *greater than or equal to*.  Why not write a method that returns the operator?

```
enum Operator { 
...
}

public Operator getOperator(String s) { 

    if(s.contains(">=")) { 
       return Operator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO;
    } else if (s.contains(">") {
       return Operator.GREATER_THAN;
    }

}
```

If the input can be a complex expression that contains multiple operators, instead of `contains`, try using `indexOf(...)` and look ahead one character for the '='.

Comment: It'll still fail on `<tag>hi there!</tag>`—that is, not fail, but not give the, err, "right" answer :)

Comment: Yes, he didn't really say alot about the data. If it's tag data, he's hosed with his current implementation.

Comment: @AmirAfghani I think this will not give correct answer if S contains both >= and >

Comment: can you elaborate it in detail?

Comment: @SRK Your specification isn't specific in this point. Since you haven't defined what should happen if the string contains both `>=` and `>` that means we can do anything without violating the spec. You'll have to fix the specification first before anything else.

Comment: @Voo My objective is to find no of operators like >=,>,<=,< etc.

suppose my string contains > and >= both and I want to find no of > then count will be 2 because of that >= whereas originally string contains one >
hope now its clear..

Comment: @SRK That should clearly be part of your question, because that's a good specification. Several ways to solve this, but a simple parser should be good enough here.

Comment: @Voo even I thought its too simple...but I am trying to solve it for last 1.5 days...and still cant solve...

Answer (score 0):

```
"your string >".contains(">");// returns true
```

Answer (score -1):

`boolean value = Pattern.compile(">").matcher("a>5").find(); // returns true`

Comment: You provide a too specific pattern match to be useful.